# HTML5 Canvas - Dragging Text on Canvas Problem

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to Drag Text which is located on the Canvas , I found a tutorial How to Drag a Rectange but i could not implement it on  text , This is the Following code for moving the rectangle , can some one help me to implement it on Text ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Drag and Drop Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>

<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas;
var ctx;
var x = 75;
var y = 50;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 3;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300;
var dragok = false;

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
 clear();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
 rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
 rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
}

function myMove(e){
 if (dragok){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
 }
}

function myDown(e){
 if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
 canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
 e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  dragok = true;
  canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
 }
}

function myUp(){
 dragok = false;
 canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

init();
canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
canvas.onmouseup = myUp;

</script>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Test](http://jsbin.com/ulowi4)**

And also when i add this Code in the HEAD tag it does not work. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 8):

Basic example
http://jsfiddle.net/h3BCq/1/

Prettied up one (kept rect function, added new text function, draws the bounding box for the text)
http://jsfiddle.net/h3BCq/2/

I definitely cheated. I used px for the font size to easier grab its width. You could use em's, or points though you would just need to do a conversion to pixels to get an estimated width. I Basically just removed rect, and added filltext, and modified the check to check for the text width.

Comment: Why doesnt this code not  work when i put all the Script code into the HEAD tag ?

Comment: In your example above you dont have a closing tag for head. Also make sure to wait until the dom is loaded. You can use something like window.onDomReady = function(){Your nifty stuff}; Also best practice you shouldnt include JS in the head, put your code on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I actually wanted a Butoon, When i click that a prompt appears and ask's me for text. that text is displayed on the canvas. if i click on the button again new Text is added up along with the old text on the canvas.

Comment: Well i kept it in the window.onDomReady = function() still it did not work [link](http://jsbin.com/ehugo5/2)  . I am a begginer So i don't know much , although i was told that the scrips are kept in the head , why are you saying not to put it there ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ehugo5/7 Also check out this link on putting scripts at the bottom, http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Comment: I just saw your Blog..! Amazing Work! :)

Comment: But the code placed in the Head also should work isnt it ? window.onDomReady = function(){ makes sure that its Loaded. Why isnt it working in the Head tag ? I actually wanted a Butoon, When i click that a prompt appears and ask's me for text. that text is displayed on the canvas. if i click on the button again new Text is added up along with the old text on the canvas could you please help me with that ?

Comment: I put my `<script>` tags below the HTML `body`, not in the `head`. I've been doing it this way because otherwise I always manage to get errors involving DOM manipulation. When the script is below the HTML, I never get those errors.

Comment: @B1KMusic yeah that is the recommended location for js files actually.