# Drag clickable URL in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

There are lots of pages that tell me how to drag a shape or image across a canvas, even drag [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017619/html5-canvas-dragging-text-on-canvas-problem). However, I want to drag texts in the form of clickable HTML URLs (hyperlinks), i.e., to group several on the one canvas to give an impression of relevancy (the closer the links to each other, the more closely they are related. (being HTML links, only their titles will be visible - the actual URLs will be hidden).

The first problem that arises is whether I can use a single left-click to either activate the link (take me to another page) or have it interpreted as the beginning of a drag. Probably I will have to use a different hotkey, such as a r-click to drag, a l-click to activate. I don't want to have to double-click to activate - an extra click becomes tedious.

I haven't found anything that specifically addresses this problem, either in this forum or elsewhere, so would be grateful for suggestions as to how to go about implementing this form of drag-and-drop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving your link will essentially be the same as moving an image. Canvas has no URL componentant or tag element - you'd have to create your own.

So you're pretty much just going to create a button with an onclick event that will call the URL associated with that button.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod. Question: If I go ahead and do this, how will Canvas distinguish between my clicking the button and dragging and dropping it?

Comment: By listening to the mouse (or touch) events you can determine this. The click event will be easy (built in) but you'll need to determine if the user is dragging. Here is a good post on dragging basics: http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Comment: Thanks for the reference Jarrod. I'll study Simon's page carefully and post back with my solution if all goes well.

Comment: Don't forget to click accept. I see you haven't accepted 7/7 of the questions you've asked. If you're not sure how, it's the tick next to the answer.